# bootstrap image gallery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I started to use the bootstrap CSS framework. There are classes to build an image gallery which basically draws a frame around the picture and consists of a listitem, an anchor and the image. The gallery does not look to good if the images are of different size. My idea was to set a fixed width and height for each thumbnail and center the image ind the border. That somewhow does not work. The tumbnail is always attached to the top of the frame.

```
<ul class="thumbnails" id="ulthumbs">
<li>
    <a class="thumbnail" style="width:120px; height:120px; line-height:120px;" >
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" style="width:120px; height:84px; vertical-align:middle">
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Ideas?

Best,
Bernhard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than using a table, there is not a cross browser way to vertically align items of an unknown height without Javascript.

[jQuery Vertical Align Plugin](http://seodenver.com/simple-vertical-align-plugin-for-jquery/)

In your case you would give the list items a fixed height and use the plugin to align the anchors (which will need to be set as block level elements).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without JS would be to set width and height of the list item and the anchor and set the image as a background of the anchor with position 50% 50%.

In that way if the image is bigger than the holder, will be cropped, or displayed with border.

Hope that would help someone searching for similar solution.